# Why would the recursive method of converting decimal to binary be faster than the iterative, using and returning strings?

Tags: c++, recursion, time, iteration

I created two functions that accept a decimal number and return the binary representation of that number. I chose a simple way to do this by concatenating on 1's and 0's to a string after some simple math. I created a iterative and recursive method to do this. Then I timed the two methods with a timer class my teacher gave me. It turned out that my recursive method was about twice as fast compared to my iterative method. Why would this be the case?

```
string CConversion::decimalToBinaryIterative(int num)
{
   string ss;
   while(num > 0)
   {
        if  (num%2 != 0)
        {
            ss = '1' + ss;
        }
        else
        {
            ss = '0' + ss;
        }
        num=num/2;
    }
    return ss;
}
string CConversion::decimalToBinaryRecursive(int num)
{
    if(num <= 0)
    { 
        return "";
    } 
    else 
    {
       if  (num%2 != 0)
       {
            return decimalToBinaryRecursive(num/2) + '1';
       }
        else
        {
            return  decimalToBinaryRecursive(num/2) + '0';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you measure time? Show that part.

Comment: Did you measure optimized or debug code?

Comment: I measured both optimized and debug code. Same results. Optimized was a few magnitudes faster.

Comment: Try just comparing two loops that do `string = string + '1'` and `string = '1' + string`.

Comment: [TCO?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's not a tail call, because it adds to the result.

Comment: @M M I am using the time.h class and using the clock functions.

Comment: Recursion vs Iteration - COOL!  After you answer why it's faster, take it a step further.  Ask yourself: If it's faster, why not use it all the time?  What is the trade off for speed?  What happens when (int num) is large?

Comment: @Barmar You're right, the append is the last thing that happens there. Do you think the compiler could be smart enough to optimize this as if it were a tail call, though?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No, you can't optimize a tail call if you have to do something with the result. It's only a tail call if you're returning the result of the call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appending a character to a `std::string` is cheaper than pre-pending one, because appending can be done without copying the string if string's capacity permits you to do so.

Prepending, however, always requires a copy of the entire string.

If you change your iterative code to this

```
string ss;
while(num > 0)
{
    if  (num%2 != 0)
    {
        ss = ss + '1';
    }
    else
    {
        ss = ss + '0';
    }
    num=num/2;
 }
 return string(ss.rbegin(), ss.rend());
```

the timing should be nearly the same, or the iterative should become narrowly faster.

Comment: Or use `std::reverse(ss.begin(), ss.end())` before returning `ss`.

Answer (score 3):

The only suspecting part is how you concatenate the strings together:

```
ss = ss + '1';  // 1

ss = '1' + ss;  // 2
```

The first one (as the recursive method has) has the chance to not shift all characters and just add a character at the end of the string.

But second one has to shift all characters to the right (or even create a new string).

To solve the issue, use `ss += 'x'` to concatenate and reverse all string at the end of function.

Comment: @M M. Yup I switched it around and the iterative function showed a faster time.

Comment: The problem is, it does not append to the string (as `operator+=` would) but it has to construct a new string from scratch. So the amount of work necessary should be identical in both cases.

Comment: Actually, the only way where the first version would be significantly faster is if the compiler would optimize this to use `operator+=` instead. In all other cases I would expect both versions to perform pretty much the same (both have to copy n+1 characters to a new string, the only difference being whether you copy the single digit or the multi digit string first).